# Como puedo hacer que me funcione para que se pueda digitar un precio por teclado con el cilo while

Tags: java, poo

me pueden ayudar con una mi cadigo ya que me piden que no valide numeros negativos e intentado varias veces pero no me da el ejercicio tiene el siguiente enunciado Cree una clase llamada Carro en el que contenga las siguientes características: a. Sus atributos sean: i. Marca. ii. Modelo. b. Añada otros 3 atributos. c. Cree el objeto. d. Imprima la información por consola. e que no valide numeros negativos solo me falta eso,lo estoy intentando con el ciclo while pero como que no me funciona mucho ya que no me da para que no me aparece para ingresar un numero  este ejercicio es sin constructor por ahora asi me lo estan enseñando.

adjunto mi codigo :

package ejercico1_clases_y_objetos;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class carro
{
//atributos del objeto carro

```
     String marca;
     String modelo;
     String color;
     String capacidad;
     String matricula;
     float precio;


    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {           
//nombre del objeto 
        
carro car=new carro(); // Se_crea_el_objeto 
car.precio=200000;

while(car.precio<=0) {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\n error:digite un valor mayor a cero");
    //JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\n vuelva a digitar un precio valido");

}
car.marca=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n   Por favor digita la marca del carro a comprar: ");
car.modelo=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n  ¿Cual es el modelo de carro que desea comprar ?: ");
car.color=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n   Por favor diga el color que desea  su carro: ");
car.capacidad=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Por favor indique de cuanta capacidad desea el carro: ");
car.matricula=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Por favor diga la matricula para su vehiculo: ");
     
    
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El carro que decide comprar es:"+car.marca+ "\n El modelo es:"+car.modelo+"\n El color es:"+car.color+"\n la capacidad es:"
+car.capacidad+"\n La matricula es:"+car.matricula +"\n la cantidad a pagar del carro es: $"+car.precio+" COP "); 

   

    
    }
```

}

Comment: Con el while lo que le estás diciendo al programa es que se cierre cuando el usuario ingresa un valor menor a 0, por lo tanto no te va a mostrar nada más.
Deberías intentar con un for y luego un if adentro para validar.

Comment: lo habia cambiado en mayor a cero cogio pero se metio en un bucle horrible

Answer (score 0):

de querer evitar que el usuario ingrese un precio negativo, podes usar un do-while ,de ingresar un numero negativo te volvera a solicitar un monto mayor a 0 ,de ingresar un precio correcto continuara con las otras solicitudes de datos

```
Carro car=new Carro(); // Se_crea_el_objeto 


do{
car.precio=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\n Digite un valor mayor a cero para el precio"));

}while(car.precio<=0);


car.marca=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n   Por favor digita la marca del carro a comprar: ");
car.modelo=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n  ¿Cual es el modelo de carro que desea comprar ?: ");
car.color=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n   Por favor diga el color que desea  su carro: ");
car.capacidad=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Por favor indique de cuanta capacidad desea el carro: ");
car.matricula=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Por favor diga la matricula para su vehiculo: ");
```